# How to make single shared library with relative paths in bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm having difficulty getting Bazel build artifacts into a releasable form.

I have a directory tree with a bazel BUILD file in each directory. Each BUILD file lists the .cpp and .h files in that directory. Here's my root BUILD file

```
cc_binary(
    name = "foo",
    linkshared = True,
    srcs = [...],
    deps = [...],
)
```

My project also depends on a third party shared library (with a single .so and tree of .h headers).

I would like, as my build output, a single .so file that requires just the dependency .so file in a path relative to my library. I don't need the header files.

When I build, I see

```
INFO: Analyzed target //:foo (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:foo up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/libfoo.so
INFO: Elapsed time: 9.626s, Critical Path: 9.48s
INFO: 35 processes: 17 internal, 18 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 35 total actions
```

When I saw this I initially thought `bazel-bin/libfoo.so` would be what I want, but when I pull it out into a separate project (so that I can ultimately release the build artifacts) and ran code that uses it, it became apparent that

- the build had produced a tree of .so files
- there are other artifacts e.g. .params files
- there are symlinks in the artifacts to both nested .so files and the external dependency

All of these are problematic.

Comment: I believe the intent is that you would reference this Bazel project in your other project or have them in the same repo and crate a cc_binary target that depends on the lib

Comment: @Taekahn .so files are my final product - I'm doing FFI and it requires .so files. I'll think about your other comments

Comment: I see. In that case you should probably take a look at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/pkg.html  I use it to package binaries, but i would think it can be applied to library files as well.

Comment: You could also try turning on static_linking for the `cc_library`, and then you, in theory, should be able to just distribute that single `.so` file. That's just a guess though.

Comment: @Taekahn do you mean `linkstatic` rather than `static_linking`? That doesn't work for me. I'll have a look at pkg

Answer (score 0):

I've got it building a single .so file, but I haven't stopped it creating symlinks to the dependency.

Following [the docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library) for `cc_library`'s `linkstatic`

> The `linkstatic` attribute has a different meaning if used on a `cc_library()` rule. For a C++ library, `linkstatic=True` indicates that only static linking is allowed, so no .so will be produced ...
>
> If `linkstatic=False`, then the build tool will create symlinks to depended-upon shared libraries in the *.runfiles area.

if I put `linkstatic=True` in the BUILD files in the tree of my project, I get a single .so out. However, it appears symbols aren't always exported so I added `alwayslink=True` which fixed that.